# No sound after resizing partition with gparted

Tags: sound, gparted

I needed to reinstall my Ubuntu, after that I used `gparted` to resize my partition. Everything went well but after reboot I don't have any sound. I tried using spotify etc. - It does not work. I used the `lspci` coommand, here is the log:

```
konrad@konrad-MS-7823:~$ lspci -v
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: hsw_uncore

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 4th Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27
    Memory at f7800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 30
    Memory at f7d14000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

As we can see there is sound device avaible. Should I reinstall the driver?

Comment: And I can still hear the sound in log-in screen. There is the standard sound like "buumbb"

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal commands `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio`, `aplay -l`, and `pactl list short sinks`? Please also make sure that the relevant audio channels in `alsamixer` (terminal) or `gnome-alsamixer` (GUI) have their volume turned up and aren’t muted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
konrad@konrad-MS-7823:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio
00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller [8086:0c0c] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller [1462:7823]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
--
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller [8086:8c20] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller [1462:d823]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
konrad@konrad-MS-7823:~$ 

 konrad@konrad-MS-7823:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC892 Digital [ALC892 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
konrad@konrad-MS-7823:~$ 

konrad@konrad-MS-7823:~$ pactl list short sinks
0   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-stereo    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
1   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
konrad@konrad-MS-7823:~$
```

Sound isn't muted.